# SslRequirement: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SslRequirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-ssl-requirement

I'm trying to add ssl to my rails 3.0.7 app using the ssl requirement gem, but when I type

```
include SslRequirement
```

into my Application controller, the app fails and I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SslRequirement
```

Anybody seen this before?

Comment: What version of SslRequirement do you have in your Gemfile.lock? It's really strange that you would see this if the Gem is in your Gemfile and you've reloaded your application. The entire source of this Gem is under 50 lines and really simple: https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement/blob/master/lib/ssl_requirement.rb

Comment: I have version 1.2.0 in the gemfile.lock

Comment: That's curious, since it's on version 0.1.0: https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement/blob/master/lib/ssl_requirement/version.rb

Comment: No wonder; someone has pushed a different fork of this to rubygems under the same name. https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/network

Comment: yes, just figured it out. There's another gem without the underscore... Just changed the gemfile to the ssl_requirement gem and it seems to be working. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept. I'm sure someone else will eventually make the same mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comments on the question indicate, you're using `gem 'sslrequirement'` in your Gemfile, which is pulling down a fork of a fork of a fork of the original, none of which (the ancestors) are the (according to the original) official repository.

To fix this, you can use the following line in your Gemfile instead (note the underscore):

```
gem 'ssl_requirement'
```

Which will pull down the appropriate Gem from https://rubygems.org/gems/ssl_requirement.